# How can I get first executing file name in different script in python?

Tags: python, file, scripting

I have 4 python script files.

- `script_1.py`
- `script_2.py`
- `script_3.py`
- `script_4.py`

`script_1.py`, `script_2.py` and `script_3.py` calls `script_4.py`

Execute files always change.

Like, `python script_1.py` / `python script_2.py` / `python script_3.py`

I want to get `script_1.py`, `script_2.py`, and `script_3.py` file name in `script_4.py` python script.

How can I get current executing file name without having to pass that information as arguments?

I tried `__name__` and `inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())` but no luck.

Both of codes are returns `script_4.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When called, `sys.argv` holds the command line arguments. The first element is the name of the script that was called (including path). To get the name of the script that was originally called you can do, in any of your files:

```py
import os
import sys

called_script_with_path = sys.argv[0]
called_script_without_path = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
```

Comment: Exactly what I want! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the module level attribute `__file__` to get the path to the current module.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.basename(__file__)
test.py
```

If you want to determine this for another file, you can import the script and still query the value:

```
>>> import os
>>> import script1
>>> os.path.basename(script1.__file__)
script1.py
```